# getting java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument:inside docker container

Tags: docker, nio, dockerfile, java

I have a java program that runs inside a docker container.
This program tries to connect to a Ipv4 socket.
I get the following Invalid argument exception

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: /135.250.15.104:6524
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:209)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:199)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:543)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:528)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.connect(SslHandler.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:543)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:543)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:914)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:208)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$2.run(Bootstrap.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
```

Now I have tried setting `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`  JVM option, but no luck.

I am using open-jdk 8 and `from java:openjdk-8u72-jre` is the entry in my DockerFile .
Note that the same IP address is ping-able from the docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved when I used `--net=host` see [docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) in my docker run command and `network_mode : "host"` in my docker-compose file see [compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

Also see a related [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032299/java-net-socketexception-when-accessing-docker-host). 
The problem seems to get exposed only when the socket connection uses a per-defined local socket address instead of letting the NIO choose a free local address.

But the exception stack trace says "Invalid argument" for the remote address which kind of is weird and that is why it took time for me to figure out the problem.